# Script does not remember to set my div to display none

Tags: javascript

I have a subscription box and I am trying to make an X close button that remembers to not display next time with web storage or cookies. when i click the close button my whole side bar is set to display none. In stead of just id="gfxhsub" .

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('mailclose').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
       return false;
    };
};
```

html

```
<div id="gfxhsub" style="margin: 2em 0.5em; height: auto;">
<span id='mailclose'><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
[newsletter_signup_form id=6]
</div>
```

Comment: and where does your code attempt to set CSS property `display: none;` ???

Comment: sorry I this script from another post on this site. i dont know JavaScript

Comment: If you can give an example of the menu/side-bar with the relevant `HTML` and `CSS` I might be able to give you a detailed solution if you can also show what you have tried.... *explanation" of why your attempt didn't work with a detailed explanation of how my method works. Also are your expectations of using this for multiple elements or just for the example you have provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this points to `<span id='mailclose'>`

this.parentNode points to `<div id="gfxhsub">`

this.parentNode.parentNode points to `<div>` parent (sidebar?)

this.parentNode.parentNode.ParentNode points to `<div>` grandparent

So when you call removeChild, you are doing so on `<div id="gfxhsub">`'s grandparent and telling it to remove `<div id="gfxhsub">`'s parent.

What you want to do (with minimal changes and assuming you want to remove the node and not hide it) is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('mailclose').onclick = function(){
var gfxhsub = document.getElementById('gfxhsub');
gfxhsub.parentNode.removeChild(gfxhsub);
return false;
};
};
</script>
```

Comment: this works perfectly but how to remember its closed on page reload

Comment: @john When navigating or reloading a page anything stored within `javascript` will be lost since this is a client-side language which is executed within the browser.

Comment: what about web storage html5 or cookies

Comment: I think you should do more research to learn more about javascript etc. Here's a writeup about web storage https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

make a class .d-none in css and just use `document.getElementById('gfxhsub').classList += "d-none"` instead of `this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);`

```css
.d-none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="gfxhsub" style="margin: 2em 0.5em; height: auto;">
  <span id='mailclose'><i class="fa fa-times"></i>X</span> [newsletter_signup_form id=6]
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('mailclose').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('gfxhsub').classList += "d-none"
      return false;
    };
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

one can use DOM manipulation ...

```
document.getElementById('mailclose').onclick = function() {
    var ele = document.getElementById('gfxhsub');
    ele.style.display = 'none';
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html shows gfxhsub is the direct parent of mailclose. However in your anonymous function you are removing the parent of the parent of gfxhsub. Instead of using so many parentNodes try

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
```

Also your question is asking about setting display to none rather than removing a node from the DOM. To do this you might use

```
this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
```